# Populate empty CSV fields using sed?

Tags: perl, csv, sed

I need to enter some value (*e.g.* `1`) into all empty cells (without any value) in a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file. How can it be done using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)?

If this is not possible with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) than can it be done with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)?

Comment: Probably, but it depends on what you mean by "into empty cell"? Can you provide [a short example](http://sscce.org) of input, [the command that you have tried to execute](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and the expected output?

Answer (score 6):

I think manipulating CSV files with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) or Perl one liners is optimistic to say the least. What if the format changes, what if one the fields contains the separator? I'd recommend using [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_XS), which is very simple and efficient. Usually, simple tasks such as what you're asking for require only a few lines. Given a properly configured `Text::CSV_XS` instance (`$csv`), it would only be a matter of:

```
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $in ) ) {
  my @new_row = map { defined $_ ? $_ : 1 } @$row;
  $csv->print( \*STDOUT, \@new_row );
}
```

If you still want to use the command line directly, you can examine [csv (App::CSV)](https://metacpan.org/module/csv), which IMO has a saner approach than the mentioned alternatives.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the input file specification is not clear.. I adapted my post with an `awk` version that tries to take quotes into account..

Answer (score 3):

It could be done with `awk`. You could try:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="") $i=1}1' FS=, OFS=, file
```

### -----

Reading Larsen's comment I realized he is right in the sense that the OP had not really posted a sample that could show whether quoted fields would occur or not.. I tried to find a simple more general approach that would try to take this into account..

```
awk '
  {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {                              # For every field
      if($i=="")                                        # it is empty 
        $i=1                                            # then make it 1 requirement OP
      else {
        f=$i                                            # set `f` to the current field
        while( gsub(/"/,"&",f )%2 && i<NF ) f=f $(++i)  # while the total number of double quotes is odd, keep adding the next field to the current field and ignore it..
      }
    }
  }
  1                                                     # print the record
' FS=, OFS=, file                                       # set the I/O field separators to `,`
```

Or in one line:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="") $i=1; else { f=$i; while( gsub(/"/,"&",f)%2 && i<NF) f=f $(++i)}}1' FS=, OFS=, file
```

Testing with this input:

```
,1997,Ford,,"Super, ""luxurious"" ,,,truck",,
0,1997,Ford,,"Super, ""luxurious"" ,,,truck",,,,
```

Produced:

```
1,1997,Ford,1,"Super, ""luxurious"" ,,,truck",1,1
0,1997,Ford,1,"Super, ""luxurious"" ,,,truck",1,1,1,1
```

Comment: +1: For the [tag:awk] approach, even though it wasn't requested, it is probably the best approach.

Comment: I adapted my post with an awk version that tries to take quotes into account..

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$ cat file
v,,v,,,v,v,,,,
,,v,,v,v,,,v,,,v
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

$ sed -e 's/^,/v,/' -e':a;s/,,/,v,/;ta' -e 's/,$/,v/' file
v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v
v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v
v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v
```

Use the `-i` option to store the changes back to the file if you are happy with them.

```
$ sed -i -e 's/^,/v,/' -e':a;s/,,/,v,/;ta' -e 's/,$/,v/' file
```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't thought of this simple solution :)

Comment: Great, if you happy with this answers please accept and upvote.

Comment: @user1240622: The canonical way to say "Thanks!" around here is [to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask)